# formula for the position of the ith one and the ith zero in an infinite binary sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, binary, combinatorics-on-words

> Define an infinite binary sequence as follows: start with 0 and repeatedly replace each 0 by $001$ and each $1$ by $0$.

> Provide, with proof, a formula for the positions of the nth one and a formula for the position of the nth zero.

> Note: I've fixed a typo below; originally, it should have said $\lfloor \sqrt{2}n\rfloor$ for the position of the nth zero.

I know the nth one is at $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{2})n\rfloor$ and that the nth zero is at $\lfloor \sqrt{2}n\rfloor$. I also know that if I let $w_1 = 0,$ and for $k\ge 2, w_k$ be the string obtained by replacing every $0$ in $w_{k-1}$ with $001$ and every 1 with a 0, then $w_k$ satisfies the recurrence $w_{k+1} = w_k w_k w_{k-1}$. However, I'm not sure how to show this by induction. It seems complicated to come up with an explicit formula in terms of ones and zeroes for $w_k$, and the inductive hypothesis doesn't seem to provide much help for the inductive step, unless I can formally deduce where the 1's and 0's are. I'm not sure how to prove the formulas for the nth one and nth zero, but I know how one can intuitively obtain them. One does this by determining the limit of $\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}}$, where $a_k$ is the number of zeroes in $w_k$ and $b_k$ is the number of ones in $w_k$. Note that $a_{k+1} = 2a_k + a_{k-1}$ and $b_k = a_{k-1}$ for $k\ge 1$, where $a_0 = 0$. After one determines the limit, one can guess that the ith one will be in approximately every $\dfrac{1}{\frac{a_k}{a_k + a_{k-1}}}\to (2+\sqrt{2})$th position.

Comment: Can you verify the first 50 digits are the following?$00100100010010001001001000100100010010010001001000$

Comment: Is "the infinite binary sequence" the limit of $w_k$, $k\to\infty$ or $w_1w_2w_3\cdots$, i.e., the concatenation of all $w_k$?

Comment: @Apass.Jack yes it's the limit of $w_k$ as $k$ goes to infinity. I think you got the first 50 digits properly, assuming it's $w_{50}.$

Comment: If I post an answer proving the claims in the question are wrong, may I get the bounty? I am a bounty hunter.  I assume $\sqrt{2n}$ means $\sqrt 2 n$, of course.

Comment: If I think your answer is correct, then I'll award the bounty. Why do you assume $\sqrt{2n}$ means $\sqrt{2}\cdot n$?

Comment: Assume "the $n$-th one is at $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{2})n\rfloor$". That means there are $n$ $1$s in the first $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{2})n\rfloor$ digits. So there are $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{2})n\rfloor - n$ $0s$ among them. The ratio of the number of digits and the number of $0$ is 
$\frac{\lfloor (2+\sqrt{2})n\rfloor}{\lfloor(2+\sqrt{2})n\rfloor - n}\to\sqrt2$. So the $n$-th zero is about $\lfloor \sqrt{2}n\rfloor$

Comment: I've reposted a corrected version here just in case it makes a difference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437111/provide-with-proof-a-formula-for-the-positions-of-the-nth-one-and-a-formula-fo

Answer (score 0):

This sequence is the Sturmian word corresponding to $1/\sqrt{2}$. See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturmian_word
and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatty_sequence
for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, but could you elaborate more? I can't see how one can easily prove my originally question based off of only the sources you provided.

Comment: There should be an easier proof for this special case.